# How can I parse a string into appropriate arguments for child_process.spawn?

Tags: node.js, parsing, command-line, child-process

I want to be able to take a command string, for example:

```
some/script --option="Quoted Option" -d --another-option 'Quoted Argument'
```

And parse it into something that I can send to `child_process.spawn`:

```
spawn("some/script", ["--option=\"Quoted Option\"", "-d", "--another-option", "Quoted Argument"])
```

All of the parsing libraries I've found (e.g. minimist, etc.) do **too much** here by parsing it into some kind of options object, etc. I basically want the equivalent of whatever Node does to create `process.argv` in the first place.

This seems like a frustrating hole in the native APIs since `exec` takes a string, but doesn't execute as safely as `spawn`. Right now I'm hacking around this by using:

```
spawn("/bin/sh", ["-c", commandString])
```

However, I don't want this to be tied to UNIX so strongly (ideally it'd work on Windows too). Halp?

Comment: It is not node.js that creates process.argv, but the shell interpreter you use. So it is system dependent. bash's interpretation will be different from that of Windows cmd.

Comment: @Michael: did you find any solution. I'm facing the same problem right now.

Comment: @Krasimir nope, never found a definitive answer. I'm still using `/bin/sh` for the time being.

Comment: If you're looking to split a command line sentence into args, then [string-argv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-argv) or [spawn-args](https://www.npmjs.com/package/spawn-args) may be helpful.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## Standard Method (no library)

You don't have to parse the command string into arguments, there's an option on `child_process.spawn` named `shell`.

### options.shell

If `true`, runs command inside of a shell.
Uses `/bin/sh` on UNIX, and `cmd.exe` on Windows.

## Example:

```js
let command = `some_script --option="Quoted Option" -d --another-option 'Quoted Argument'`

let process = child_process.spawn(command, [], { shell: true })  // use `shell` option

process.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(data)
})

process.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(data)
})

process.on('close', (code) => {
  console.log(code)
})
```

Answer (score 5):

The [`minimist-string`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/minimist-string) package might be just what you're looking for.

Here's some sample code that parses your sample string -

```
const ms = require('minimist-string')
const sampleString = 'some/script --option="Quoted Option" -d --another-option \'Quoted Argument\'';
const args = ms(sampleString);
console.dir(args)
```

This piece of code outputs this -

```
{
  _: [ 'some/script' ],
  option: 'Quoted Option',
  d: true,
  'another-option': 'Quoted Argument'
}
```

Comment: How can you then turn that data into a child_process command? If you turned those key/value pairs back into a string would you know that `d` needs 1 `-` instead of 2. Same with `option`.