# nodejs spawn command with string not array?

Tags: node.js

I'm working on `spawn` on nodejs. previously I was using `exec` but exec has no compatibility in stdout (or stderr) steaming. 
now, I have a disability about spawn. It seems whereas exec accepted quoted string command, spawn does not accepted that one, just array format.

so following exec script is working correctly but another one which uses spawn will be error, due to string formatted command not array.

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;

exec(` echo foo bar `, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if ( error ){ console.log(error) }
  if ( stdout ){ console.log(stdout) }
  if ( stderr ){ console.log(stderr) }
});
```

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

command = spawn('echo foo bar');

command.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log(data.toString());
});

command.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log( data.toString());
});

command.on('exit', function (code) {
  console.log( code.toString());
});
```

I have a lot of command line script which is what I want to `spawn` on nodejs, and all of them are complicated, something like following one. that's why I want to use string format for specify command rather than array. Any idea?

```
exec(' bash -ic "expecto \\"sudo bash -ic \\\\\\"rd ; backup_important_batch\\\\\\"\\" $PASSWORD" ', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if ( error ){ console.log(error) }
    if ( stdout ){ console.log(stdout) }
    if ( stderr ){ console.log(stderr) }
});
```

Comment: You can use the `{shell: true}` option, as seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45134890/2441655

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try auto splitting the command like:

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

let cmd = 'echo foo bar'
let cmdarray = cmd.split(" ");
let command = spawn(cmdarray.shift(), cmdarray);
```

Comment: This is not a good solution, what do you do with arguments of two words with a space `--key="some value"`

Answer (score 11):

You can't split on spaces because many command line args may include strings like `./foo.js --bar "Hello Baz"`, splitting on the string will incorrectly give you `"Hello` `Baz"` as arguments.

Use a library like https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-argv to convert the string into arguments that you can pass the string to, get an array result and build your `spawn()` call.

Edit: Here's an example:

```js
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const { parseArgsStringToArgv } = require('string-argv');

async function run(command) {
    return new Promise( resolve => {
        let args = parseArgsStringToArgv(command);
        let cmd = args.shift();

        console.log(cmd, args);

        let step = spawn(cmd, args);

        step.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
        step.stderr.pipe(process.stderr);

        step.on('close', (code) => {
           resolve(code);
        });
    });
}

let name = 'Baz';
let exitCode = await run(`echo "Hello ${name}"`);
```

Answer (score 1):

As per Venryx's comment above, which links the existing answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/45134890/2441655 , you can use `spawn(cmd, [], { shell: true })`.

e.g.

```js
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const command = spawn('echo foo bar', [], { shell: true });
// alternative, as per comment by ZuzEL:
// spawn('echo foo bar', { shell: true }) 

command.stdout.on('data',data => console.log(data.toString()));
command.stderr.on('data', function (data) {console.log( data.toString());});
command.on('exit', function (code) {console.log( code.toString());});

// foo bar
//
// 0
```

See  Node.js docs for spawn [here](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processspawncommand-args-options).

(Note that you can also use `spawn(cmd, { shell: true })`, without the empty array as second argument, as per the comment below).

Comment: You can avoid second argument. This also works `spawn(cmd, { shell: true })`